# DateTime input format?

Tags: wpf, datetime, string-formatting

there's something I can't quite get my head around. Just hoping someone could please help.

I've a WPF TextBox that is bound to a DateTime property, as follows;

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DOB, StringFormat='{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}" />
```

If I enter the text '01/30/2013' it correctly converts and displays it as '30/01/2013'.
If I enter the text '30/01/2013' it throws a validation error, as it expects the INPUT to be in the format MM/dd/YYYY.

How can I change the input format?
I realise I can write a custom converter. I was just wondering if there was another way?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this trick. Add `Startup` event handle in `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application x:Class="YourClass.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="Application_Startup" ... />
```

In `App.xaml.cs` add this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
    }
}
```

Now, the date should be displayed depending on the current culture, so when you enter a date in the format of their culture, validation error should not be appear.

Answer (score 0):

Running that in debug mode, I get the following conversion failure:

> ConvertBack cannot convert value '30/01/2013' (type 'String').
>   BindingExpression:Path=Date; DataItem='MainWindowViewModel'
>   (HashCode=19342748); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Text' (type 'String')
>   FormatException:'System.FormatException: String was not recognized as
>   a valid DateTime.

It looks like it uses a default converter which uses something along the lines of `DateTime.Parse`.

The following fails with the same exception:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("30/01/2013");
```

It looks like your only options is to write your own converter.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. Same error (NB: I assume it's the same error, as I'm not displaying the validation error. The TextBox's border is red)

Comment: You should be able to view the conversion failure in the output window if you're in debug mode.  If that helps.